# android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu; unexpected end of document

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I am using the inbuilt navigation Activity (activity->navigation drawer activity).

It was working fine till now but now I am getting error message

```
   com.focus.abhishek.ftouchutility, PID: 2119
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.focus.abhishek.ftouchutility/com.focus.abhishek.ftouchutility.ModulesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                at com.focus.abhishek.ftouchutility.ModulesActivity.onCreate(ModulesActivity.java:46)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at com.focus.abhishek.ftouchutility.ModulesActivity.onCreate(ModulesActivity.java:46) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected end of document
                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:205)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:118)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:246)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:171)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:97)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at com.focus.abhishek.ftouchutility.ModulesActivity.onCreate(ModulesActivity.java:46) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

i.e.: the error is in my main Activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_modules);
```

Here is activity_modules xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_modules"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_modules_drawer" />
```

build.gradle

```
  android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.focus.abhishek.ftouchutility"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.4@aar'
}
```

Style.xml

```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="ToolbarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

@menu/activity_modules_drawer:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_allocation"
            android:icon="@drawable/nav_allocation"
            android:title="@string/nav_Allocation" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tracker"
            android:icon="@drawable/nav_tracker"
            android:title="@string/nav_Tracker" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_sync"
            android:icon="@drawable/nav_sync"
            android:title="@string/nav_Sync" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_upload_doc"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/nav_Upload" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_pending_upload"
            android:icon="@drawable/pending_upload"
            android:title="@string/nav_Upload_pending" />
    </group>


        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
                android:icon="@drawable/nav_profile"
                android:title="@string/nav_Profile" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_change_pass"
                android:icon="@drawable/nav_changepass"
                android:title="@string/nav_Change_pass" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_Logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/nav_logout"
                android:title="@string/nav_Logout" />
        </menu>

</menu>
```

Comment: Your error says `line #16`. You didn't show 16 lines of XML

Comment: android.support.design.widget.NavigationView this is 16th line in Binary xml file

Comment: Sure, but can you show all the logcat? Most importantly... `Caused by` lines

Comment: added the caused line...error is regarding navigationdrawer my friend

Comment: There are more lines containing `Caused by` with the actual error. Please add

Comment: I had post whole error sorry for appearing error like this...

Comment: show your `@menu/activity_modules_drawer`

Comment: Post your header layoout and menu xml files

Comment: editted @kiranBennyJoseph

Comment: thank you @kiranBennyJoseph to take me on that error file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply learn to read the logcat, you see...

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected end of document
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:205)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:118)
```

So, you see **Menu**Inflater, and this in your XML with an error

```
@menu/activity_modules_drawer
```

So you open that file, and you look at it.

You have two `<menu>` tags, but you only have one of those in that file, so you have an *Unexpected end of document*

---

Try this fixed one.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_allocation"
            android:icon="@drawable/nav_allocation"
            android:title="@string/nav_Allocation" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tracker"
            android:icon="@drawable/nav_tracker"
            android:title="@string/nav_Tracker" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_sync"
            android:icon="@drawable/nav_sync"
            android:title="@string/nav_Sync" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_upload_doc"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/nav_Upload" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_pending_upload"
            android:icon="@drawable/pending_upload"
            android:title="@string/nav_Upload_pending" />
    </group>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/nav_profile"
        android:title="@string/nav_Profile" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_change_pass"
        android:icon="@drawable/nav_changepass"
        android:title="@string/nav_Change_pass" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_Logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/nav_logout"
        android:title="@string/nav_Logout" />

</menu>
```

Comment: I wanna ask one thing how can i put last logout think fixed at bottom and other in list?

Comment: Not sure what that means, sorry

Comment: I mean whole items which are present in navigation drawer are in listview I want one fix item which should not scroll..

Comment: If your items scroll, then you have too many in your menu xml. I don't have a fix for that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

A typical menu items of a drawer would look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools"/>
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send"/>
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

Find out what is wrong with yours

Comment: Thanks Samuel i had done same but there is only one right ans tick from my side....Thanks alot.